# value ranking based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, ranking, unique-values

I Need to rank Dealers based on their Sales value and in regards to the Group and Country they belong to per month. It should look like this:

```
DealerID Month Country Group SalesValue   Ranking
 12344    1    Germany Sales   120         1
 23345    1    Schweiz Sales   140         3
 23346    1    Schweiz Sales   160         2
 23347    1    Schweiz Sales   180         1 
 12350    1    Germany Sales   110         2
```

In SQL it would be similar to a rank function combined with a Group by month Country and Group. How can I achieve this in Excel?

Thank you!!

Comment: The ranking is Primary based on the salesvalue per Group, Country and month the dealer is assigned to. Group can have different values as well as Month, Country and dealerID. Each Dealer is assigned to a Country and a Group. The ranking is based on the salesvalue they achieved categorized by Country,Group and month. I achieved to get close to the Ranking i want ot achieve by following :                                               Formula =SUMPRODUCT((--(B:B=[@Group]));(--(C:C=[@Country]));(--(D:D=[@Month]));(--([@SalesValue]<V:V)))+1

Comment: However the solution I found takes way too Long to calculate, so I cannot use it. Does anyone has another better solution?